# How to protect PROD Secrets in Azure Function Code?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

It would help me immensely if someone could shed light on how to get secrets into PROD code without a developer having `Contributor` role on an Azure Function.

**Acronyms**:

- "SAMI" = System-assigned Managed Identity
- "Ent Sec" = Enterprise Security Team

**Flow (adapted from [this Azure Key Vault Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#example))**:

- Ent Sec team uploads secrets to DEV KeyVault and provides developer with DEV Secret reference
- Ent Sec team adds SAMI to KeyVault Access Policy (Developer is not in access policy)
- Developer adds DEV Secret reference to Azure Function App Setting (via `local.settings.json` or `App Settings` in Azure Portal)
- Developer gets DEV code running end-to-end

**Visual**:

[image]

**Questions**:

- How is this going to work for PROD code?

  - IF Developer has `Contributor` role on the PROD Azure Function code, all secrets are visible them; this negates the Azure Key Vault Access Policy (which only allows the App SAMI to access) and the use of Azure Key Vault Secret References.
- Is there another role that can be granted to Developer?
- Would Ent Sec be responsible for adding PROD Secrets to the PROD code?
- Is there a DevOps pipeline that "injects" the correct secret depending on the ENV?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand your entire setup... this should be fairly easy by using KeyVault-referenced App Settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

The developer might have access to the app settings, but will only see something like this: `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)`

Only the Managed Identity of the App Service / Function App needs to have an access policy in the Key Vault. If the developer does not, they will not be able to see the actual secret.

Comment: That was my original understanding as well, but I found a hole in this. Anyone with `Contributor` role on the Azure Function, even though they are NOT LISTED in the KeyVault Access Policy, CAN SEE secrets in plaintext EVEN WHEN REFERENCES ARE USED IN THE SOURCE CODE. They just have to visit `https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env`. In response to my Bug Bounty report on the issue, I was told this is "Intended behavior" and not a bug.

Comment: Also, [MS says](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/60130#issuecomment-675179324) that a dev with `Contribute` role can `...run any software they want using identity and have access to everything that identity has.` Hence my post here...

Comment: you might have wanted to post the link to your discussion in the github repo in your original post... so not sure what you are looking for exactly? the general guidance was shared there: no dev should have write access (such as Contributor role) to PROD. only deploy to prod using service principles etc.

Comment: I was told to post here for best practices. I'm looking for the "How". How do I safely get secrets into the PROD code? What is the pattern to `"...deploy to prod using service principals etc."`?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for guidance on...`no dev should have write access (such as Contributor role) to PROD. only deploy to prod using service principles etc.`. How is PROD Function code deployed using service principals?